# How to get email-to-item email address for podio item?

Tags: podio

I think I am clear with the the title. What I am thinking is that. I can send an email with attachments to any email address and include the link of my podio item or any other info I am not sure. and the attachments from the email will be added to that specific podio item.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Podio is working like that already. 
With only limitations that it should be not `any email address` but very specific `email-to-item` email address. Which you can find from Podio item page

[image: email-to-item]

There will be very secret email address which you can then use to create new comments to specific Podio item. And yes, you can include attachments and those will be added to comments as attachments.

And here are more details: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201290603-Email-to-item

---

To get that email address from **API** and not from UI: https://developers.podio.com/doc/email/get-email-contact-for-reference-13716555

Working **curl** example:

```
curl 
    -H "Authorization: OAuth2 <access_token>" 
    "https://api.podio.com/email/contact/item_comment_user/item/<item_id>"
```

And then, you will have to parse the response like:

```
{"mail":"some-pretty-random-piece-of-text7@some-other-pretty-weird-domain.podio.com","name":"Comment on item on Podio"}
```

Comment: What I just want to know is that. Can I just get this email of an item through API ?